# Finding positive integer solutions $(x,y)$ such that $x^2y+x+y$ is divisible by $xy^2+y+7$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

How many pairs of positive integers $(x,y)$ exist such that $x^2y+x+y$ is divisible by $xy^2+y+7$?

I try a lot and tried different ways but they didn't help me.

Comment: $\frac{x^2y+x+y}{xy^2+y+7}$ is merely an expression.  Is it supposed to equal something?  Is it supposed to meet some other constraint?

Comment: First, you should fix grammatical and mathematical errors in your question.  Are you asking how many pairs of natural numbers $(x,y)$ exist such that $x^2y+x+y$ **is divisible** by $xy^2+y+7$?  Also, do you include $0$ as a natural number or not?

Comment: If you include zero, then every pair of the form $(7n,0)$ works, so infinitely many in that case.

Comment: @JMoravitz I exactly mean what you said and  0 is not a natural number

Comment: Well you should say that in your problem, you are not considering $0$ as a natural number. Whether $0$ is a natural number or not is context dependent that's why I prefer to write positive integers or non-zero integers in such ambiguous cases.

Comment: I'll pay attention from the next question

Comment: It is also worth being more careful with question phrasing since the phrase "$x$ is divisible by $y$" is different than "$x$ divides $y$".  The first means that there is an integer $k$ such that $x=yk$ while the second means there is an integer $k$ such that $y=xk$.  Using a phrase other than these two like you had originally makes it ambiguous which was meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the source of your problem then google is a better way than MSE.

IMO $1998$ problem $4$

[See this](http://sms.math.nus.edu.sg/Simo/IMO_Problems/98.pdf)

Comment: Wow! I solved an Olympic question...

Answer (score 2):

Infinite pairs like the following:

If $x=7n^2;\;y=7n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}-\{0\}$   the expression can be written as $$\frac{x^2 y+x+y}{x y^2+y+7}=\frac{343 n^5+7 n^2+7 n}{343 n^4+7 n+7}=n$$
Furthermore there is a solution $x=11;\;y=1$ for which the fraction reduces to $7$

Comment: +1 for you efforts but note that you are still missing $x=49,y=1$